# Set height of div but keep fluid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a situation where I need to make a div the same size as an absolutely positioned sidebar. I sorted that using this bit of jQuery;

```
$('#main').height('auto');
top_height = $('.toolbar').outerHeight();
side_height = $('#RightSideBar').height();
body_height = $('#main').innerHeight();
console.log(body_height + '  ' + side_height);
if (body_height < side_height){
    $('#main').height(side_height + top_height);
}
else {
    $('#main').height(body_height);
}
```

I have ran into a new problem due to the dynamic nature of some content on some pages. Since the height of `#main` is absolutely set if the size of its content increases the size of the div will not increase with it and vice versa.

I need the div to be set the same height as the sidebar and remain fluid with its content. So the div would increase and decrease in height up to the height of the sidebar.

I hope that is easily understandable, if its not please say so.

Comment: are you saying the height of the main content should never be shorter than the sidebar but needs to be able to grow taller if its content is bigger?

Comment: @willanderson Exactly! But this needs to be dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without javascript. You need a relative positioned parent that will auto size to side bar and then an absolute positioned div that adopts 100% height of parent. Never is there a set height, always fluid.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/nSBaA/1/

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
#main {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
}
#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: This will not work as the `#main` div is positioned absolutely it is only ever the size of the sidebar and will not lengthen with its content

Comment: Please look at this edited version of your fiddle and you should see what I mean [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nSBaA/6/)

Comment: Then you can change the display property to `display: table-cell` DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/LFEF5/40/

Answer (score 1):

instead of setting the `height` of `#main` with your calculations, try setting the `min-height`:

```
if (body_height < side_height){
    $('#main').css('min-height', side_height + top_height);
}
else {
    $('#main').css('min-height', body_height);
}
```